# Is there a way to completely reset progress on the Terra Nil Demo?

Tags: terra-nil-demo

I'd like to reset the demo version of [Terra Nil](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1593030/Terra_Nil/), so that someone else that uses the same PC as me can experience it from a "fresh" perspective, i.e. going through the tutorial section again.

I've tried deleting local files and reinstalling the demo, but it keeps jumping back to the point where you've already unlocked the water pump.

Is there something else I need to do to completely reset the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some settings are stored in the Windows Registry, you'll need to remove them to completely reset the demo:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and type `regedit`
- On the Window that appears, navigate to the following location:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Free Lives/`
- Select the folder called `Terra Nil Demo`, and delete it.

This should reset the tutorial.